# How to split a file up in sections in php?

Tags: php, file, split, sections

My script stores serialized arrays in text files, but I would like to be able to split the files up in sections and store data within those sections.  I have though about using text as separation, and then use substring to get data between two substrings in the file, but is there a better way (faster, easier, more reliable etc...)?

Like this:

```
Data set 1
-------------
Data set 2
------------
Data set 3
```

The only problem is that one of the data sets(serialized arrays) might contain the text used as splitpoints...

Comment: This was formatted wrong...  there was supposed to be  ---(..)-- between the lines...

Comment: Do you want to store textual data only? Or will the arrays contain binary data as well?

Answer (score 3):

How about storing those in JSON format? You could have a top level object representing an array of data sets or simply a list of name/value pairs like in the example bellow. Advantage of such approach would be that you have a bunch of parsers which can be used for reading/writing JSON.

Example:

```
{
    "data_set_1" : "serialized array data for data set 1",
    "data_set_2" : "serialized array data for data set 2",
    "data_set_3" : "serialized array data for data set 3"
}
```